# React Native - Can't access to contacts, calendar in iOS release mode

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm developing an app with React Native and I'm struggling with the access to the contacts, calendar and maybe more "native features".

I'm using

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.9",
"react-native-add-calendar-event": "2.3.1",
"react-native-contacts": "^3.1.4",
```

When trying my app on Android or the iOS simulator I can access everything (contacts and calendar) but when I release my iOS app: I have the alert to allow permissions and then nothing happen ... No contacts or nothing added to the calendar.

I began to understand I had a problem when I faced the issue with the calendar whatever package I used in my app.

I think I have a difference/problem between dev and release mode for accessing native phone features but I'm not really sure that my "contacts" and "calendar" issues are linked to the same problem.

Do someone have an idea about why I could not access any of those features in my app releases ?

Comment: Did you add "NSContactsUsageDescription" and the reason for accessing contacts to your info.plist? 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW14

Comment: Yes, I added "NSContactsUsageDescription"